# Dumbfounded by Twilio API to send a simple text message

Tags: java, sms, twilio

I have an account with Twilio and I was using it to programatically send myself text messages via a PHP script.  Now I want this functionality within a service I am writing.  My issue is the lack of good examples on how to implement the functionality in Java.  There seems to be only one example of what I want to do, but I keep getting errors in eclipse (neon) saying there is an error in the constructor for PhoneNumber(String).  I will show you my code first and then explain.

I have these two classes, one to store my user credentials, and one class to hold message recipient data (a name and a phone number)....ps forgive the formatting.

```
/**
 * Class contains my credentials with Twilio.com
 * and are read from a file located at /sms_textdata/twiliocredentials.txt
 */
public class SMSCredentials
{
private final String userID;
private final String accessCode;
private final String senderNumber;

public SMSCredentials(String userID,  String accessCode, String senderNumber)
{
    this.userID = userID;
    this.accessCode = accessCode;
    this.senderNumber = senderNumber;
}

public String getUserID()
{
    return userID;
}

public String getAccessCode()
{
    return accessCode;
}

public String getSenderNumber()
{
    return senderNumber;
}
}



/**
 * A class that models a recipient of a text message
 * Recipient list is located at /sms_textdata/smsrecipients.txt
 */
public class MessageRecipient
{
//first name
private String name;
//phone number
private String phoneNumber;

public MessageRecipient(String name, String phoneNumber)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getNumber()
{
    return phoneNumber;
}
}
```

The third class I have implements the above two classes.  I am planning to read the credential data and recipient data from two text files.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.rest.lookups.v1.PhoneNumber;

/**
*  This class is responsible for sending  SMS text messages
* to a list of recipients.
*/
public class SMSAlert
{
private SMSCredentials credentials;
private ArrayList<MessageRecipient> recipients;

public SMSAlert()
{
    this.getCredentials();
    this.createRecipientList();
}

/**
* send a SMS text message to a list of recipients
*/
public void sendSMSTextMessage()
{
    //send messages to a list of recipients 
    Twilio.init(credentials.getUserID(), credentials.getAccessCode());

    for(MessageRecipient rec : recipients)
    {
        Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(rec.getNumber()), 
                                        new PhoneNumber(credentials.getSenderNumber()),
                                        " Hey " + rec.getName() + " the garage door is open!")
                                        .create();
        //System.out.println(message.getSid());
    }
}

/**
* create an object containing the credentials required from Twilio.com
*/
private void getCredentials()
{
    String credentialsFile;
    Scanner credentialIn = null;
    String id = null;
    String code = null;
    String number = null;

    try
    {
        credentialsFile = "~/Documents/twiliocredentials.txt";
        credentialIn = new Scanner(new File(credentialsFile));

        // as there are only two strings in this file, the loop will execute
        //only once, and assign the values to a new object of type SMSCredentials.
        while(credentialIn.hasNext())
        {
            id = credentialIn.next();
            code = credentialIn.next();
            number = credentialIn.next();
        }

        //create the credentials object from a file
        credentials = new SMSCredentials(id, code, number);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        credentialIn.close();
    }
}

/**
* create a list of recipients from a file to send text messages to.
*/
private void createRecipientList()
{
    recipients = new ArrayList<MessageRecipient>();
    String userFile;
    Scanner recipientsIn = null;
    String name;
    String number;

    try
    {
        userFile = "~/Documents/smsrecipients.txt";
        recipientsIn = new Scanner(new File(userFile));

        //file format is name : number pair on one line of text
        //one object is instantiated per line/user
        while(recipientsIn.hasNext())
        {
            name = recipientsIn.next();
            number = recipientsIn.next();

            //instantiate and add a user to the list
            recipients.add(new MessageRecipient(name, number));
        }           
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        recipientsIn.close();
    }
}
}
```

The error I keep getting in eclipse is from the method sendSMSTextMessage().  Eclipse is giving me the error:

```
The constructor PhoneNumber(String) is undefined
```

This is a Maven project, and I have all of my dependencies.....  What am I missing?  Does anyone have a better way for me to send multiple text messages within Java?  Shouldn't there me a method for 'send message'?

Thanks for your help...my brain is fried....

Mike

Comment: please ignore the file paths for now..... i was trying to do testing and was referring to a local directory.

Comment: The java part is easy; looking at https://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/com/twilio/rest/lookups/v1/PhoneNumber.html you can see the PhoneNumber class has no public constructor (and so no constructor that takes a String).    Now, how to create one, is a different thing :) maybe there's a builder class ? Maybe that's not the right class to use ? it seems they have at least one more PhoneNumber class in a different package ...

Comment: Quick google agrees with what @okaram was getting at.  Need to use [lookups](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups)

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/sending-via-rest

The code here is what I replicated.  I am not sure I understand the PhoneNumber class...there is a few of them.

Comment: @mike, the PhoneNumber class you want is  com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber ; try replacing  your import com.twilio.rest.lookups.v1.PhoneNumber; with import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

Comment: @okaram, Ii tried that but I get the same error.

Comment: facing the same issue now. What was your solution for it @mike?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you're importing the wrong definition of `PhoneNumber`. You are getting it from `com.twilio.rest.lookups.v1.PhoneNumber` however the [Twilio guide to sending an SMS message with Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-send-sms-messages-in-java) imports `com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I noticed that myself last night, and corrected it....however I am still having issues with the current version of the API... I don't have the computer that this code is on with me, but I will share the exact problem I am facing later tonight.  On another note, if I use the version 6 of the API, everything compiles, but if I try to execute the code within the runtime environment, an exception is thrown....which confuses me more because the code works fine in a stand alone application.

Comment: Ok, it's best if you post the new issue as a new question, which I should get around to looking at soon enough. I think I saw your other question, but I can't answer that myself as I don't regularly build Java applications. I am more useful on the API side :)

Comment: Phil, I wanted to email you but can't figure out how to on this site.  I recently posted a related question regarding this same issue and was hoping you could take a look at it for me...

Comment: Hi @mike, is that the Dropwizard question? I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that, I'm newer to Maven and Dropwizard than you are!

Comment: no prob, just thought I would ask.  I spoke with a friend and he firmly believes I have a dependency issue, so I need to spend some time properly learning to work with Maven.